# Need help figuring out what I need to change to implement the required changes

Tags: c, fork, waitpid

I tried some approaches but couldnt make it work, the specifications are next, thank you

Using the fork and waitpid functions, implement a new version of this program in which processing performed by the remover_ruido is divided into 16 processes.

My first approach was using this:

```
  const int NPROCESSES = 16;   
  pid_t pids[128];

  for (int i = 0; i < NPROCESSES;i ++) {
     pids[i] = fork();
     if (!pids[i]) {  
       remover_ruido(amostras_out, amostras_in, n_amost);
       exit(0);
  }
}

 for (int i = 0; i < NPROCESSES; i++)
      waitpid(pids[i], 0, 0);
```

I did a smilar project but using threads, where was asked to divide the process in 50 threads. I dont know if i can use the same method or not.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NMIN 4000

double mytime();
void *malloc_pshared(size_t size);      // aloca memória partilhada entre processos
void remover_ruido(short *dados_out, short *dados_in, int nelem);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n_amost;

    if (argc != 2 || (n_amost = atoi(argv[1])) < NMIN) {
        printf("Sintaxe: \"%s N\", com N não inferior a %d\n", argv[0], NMIN);
        exit(1);
    }

    short *amostras_in = (short *) malloc_pshared(sizeof(short) * n_amost);

    if (amostras_in == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_amost; ++i)
            amostras_in[i] = i * 1.0;
    }

    short *amostras_out = (short *) malloc_pshared(sizeof(short) * n_amost);

    if (amostras_out == NULL)
        exit(1);

    double t0 = mytime();

    remover_ruido(amostras_out, amostras_in, n_amost);

    printf("Tempo de execução: %f (s)\n", mytime() - t0);

    return 0;
}

double mytime() {
   struct timeval tp;
   struct timezone tzp;

   gettimeofday(&tp,&tzp);
   return ( (double) tp.tv_sec + (double) tp.tv_usec * 1.e-6 );
}

 void *malloc_pshared(size_t size){
      return mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED| MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
}

void remover_ruido(short *dados_out, short *dados_in, int nelem)
{
    // não implementada
    for (int i = 0; i != nelem; ++i)
        dados_out[i] = sqrt(dados_in[i] * dados_in[i]);
}
```

Comment: _I tried some approaches but couldnt make it work_ Please _edit_ your question and post this code in an additional code block. _Exactly_ what did you try and what were the results. Describe the general approach you were taking.

Comment: i did someting similiar to that but using threads, where they asked me to divide the process in 50 threads. my problem here is that i tried the same aproach, but gives me error every time

Comment: Where's `malloc_pshared`?

Comment: I edit it out, but i put it back again @Armali

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight refactor to split up the data on a per process basis. I coded it but didn't compile or test it:

```
const int NPROCESSES = 16;
pid_t pids[128];

int chunksize = n_amost / NPROCESSES;       // number of elements per process
int remain = n_amost;                       // number of elements remaining
int curoff;                                 // current offset into arrays
int cursize;                                // current length for process

for (int i = 0; i < NPROCESSES; i++, remain -= cursize) {
    pids[i] = fork();
    if (! pids[i]) {
        // get index into arrays for this process
        curoff = i * chunksize;

        // assume we're a middle process -- use the calculated length
        cursize = chunksize;

        // last process must get the remainder of the array
        if (i >= (NPROCESSES - 1))
            cursize = remain;

        remover_ruido(&amostras_out[curoff], &amostras_in[curoff], cursize);
        exit(0);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < NPROCESSES; i++)
    waitpid(pids[i], 0, 0);
```

Note that there are other ways to do the split up of the offset/length but this should get you started

Note that you should double check your `mmap` call in to be sure it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This variant is quite similar to Craig Estey's, with the difference that it actually works, because it doesn't modify a variable in a child under the assumption it would be modified in the parent. ;-)

Only your *first approach*'s line

```
       remover_ruido(amostras_out, amostras_in, n_amost);
```

needs to be changed to

```
       int from = n_amost*i/NPROCESSES,
             to = n_amost*(i+1)/NPROCESSES;
       remover_ruido(amostras_out+from, amostras_in+from, to-from);
```

Comment: if i need to check if every process is running what code did i need to add

Comment: From which process do you want to _check if every process is running_? Whichever one you choose, you would have to prevent every running process from finishing earlier than the time when it will be checked. And what's the point of this check? You already check that every process **has** run with the `waitpid` loop.

Comment: I forgot one thing: To see if a process couldn't be started, we should add e. g. `if (pids[i] == -1) perror("fork");` after the `fork()` line.